# Sails.js and Waterline: Finding Where Search Term is in the Array or Nested Object

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to write a complex find query using Waterline from Sails.js. Here's a simplified example of the object that I'm doing the find on:

[image: object description]

Basically, I want to write a query where a provided search string could be equal to the `id`, be in the `myArray` attribute, or be the value of `myNestedObject.nestedAttribute`.

I know that I can do an or like this:

```
MyModel.find().where({ or: [] });
```

That array that is provided as the `or` in the `.where()` is where the matches should be added, like this:

```
{ id: { 'contains': searchTerm } }
```

How do I do a query using Waterline where I can provide a search term (`searchTerm`) to see if that value is in the `myArray` object? And how can I check nested attributes? I am using the sails-mongo adapter, but I'd like to not write any Mongo specific queries so that I can have all the benefits of using an ORM in the future (like if we move off Mongo or something).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not possible to search within embeds using standard waterline query syntax, however you can try:

1. Structuring your data differently.
2. Using a [mongo native query](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html).
3. Using [.stream()](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/stream) and check each record one by one if this query isn't
   latency-sensitive (e.g. a scheduled job or migration script).